# Black area showing after popping view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UINavigationController` inside a `UITabBarController`. I push a view onto the stack which has the `Hide Bottom Bar on Push` option set to true. This successfully hides the tab bar and pushes the view. Then when I press the back button, it pops back to the initial view controller and seems to offset the bottom of the view by the same height as the tab bar. It looks like this occurs after the pop transition has finished. This leaves a "black bar" area directly above my tab bar. What is going on here? If I don't have `hide bottom bar on push` enabled, it works fine.

**EDIT**
I just tried enabling `Extend Edges Under Opaque Bars` and it fixed the problem. Can anyone tell me why this fixes the problem?!

Comment: can you add your code , how you are hiding the bottom bar?

Comment: @KunalGupta It's literally through the checkmark on storyboard, no code involved.

Comment: Have you tried making your tabbar translucent where you hide the tabbar?

    [self.tabBar setTranslucent:YES];

Answer (score 0):

The edgesForExtendedLayout & extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars property, determines whether or not view controllers' views underlap top and bottom bars (navigation bar, toolbar, etc.)

By default, they do not underlap, which is why when you disabled/hid it, you were getting "black space."